# One sprite group will not update while the others update just fine

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

This is my first post on here; I usually troll the topics until I find my answer, but this particular problem is so very puzzling that I don't think I can easily get the solution by searching around.

Anyway, I have made the beginnings of a side-scrolling space shooter. Thus far, all of my updates have been processed with zero qualms - I simply use `spriteGroup.update()` calls in the `UpdateManager` object for my various sprite groups (player, player weapons, player thrust, etc.) However, upon constructing a new sprite type, `Drone`, I have painstakingly tried again and again and again to get the `drones` group to update - embedding the update in player controls, putting it in with the list of other updates, and even built a dev key specifically to force the update of the drone - all to no avail. The drone's starting image will appear in the place where I pressed the key, and then it does nothing after that. I added a test instruction to the Drone's `update()` method to simply print "drone update" once it is accessed, but nothing prints to the terminal. When performing tests on keypresses, everything under the keypress conditional processes EXCEPT the `drones.update()` command, so it appears that it is somehow being ignored entirely.

I cannot imagine what I could possibly be doing wrong - I've compared the Drone object to various other sprite objects that I've created, and it's built virtually the exact same way as my other sprites. It simply has to be something to do with the sprite groups; at this point I feel like I just have to be missing something about it that is not terribly obvious.

At any rate, here's some of my code:

**Player Class**

```
player_weapons = pg.sprite.Group()
drones = pg.sprite.Group()

""" PLAYER """
class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.image = pg.image.load( os.path.join("gfx", "ares", "Ares.png"))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = (SCREEN_W / 2) - (self.rect.width / 2)
        self.rect.y = (SCREEN_H / 2) - (self.rect.height / 2)
        self.playerPos = self.rect.center

        self.lives = 0
        self.droneCount = 0
        self.speed = 3
        self.bulletPower = 1
        self.bulletPause = 0
        self.cannonCharge = 0

        self.alive = False

    def update(self, pressed_keys):

        self.updateDrones = False 

        """ PLAYER CONTROLS """ # <~~~~~ I had earlier added drones.update() to player movement (no luck)
        # UP
        if pressed_keys[K_UP] or pressed_keys[K_w]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, -self.speed)

        # DOWN
        if pressed_keys[K_DOWN] or pressed_keys[K_s]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, self.speed)

        # LEFT
        if pressed_keys[K_LEFT] or pressed_keys[K_a]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)


        # RIGHT
        if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT] or pressed_keys[K_d]:
            self.rect.move_ip(self.speed, 0)


        # AUTOFIRE
        if pressed_keys[K_KP_4] or pressed_keys[K_l]:
            self.bulletPause += 1

            if self.bulletPause == 7:
                new_bullet = PlayerBullet(player.rect.centerx + 18, player.rect.centery + 4)
                player_weapons.add(new_bullet)
                all_sprites.add(new_bullet)

                new_flash = BulletFlash(player.rect.centerx + 18, player.rect.centery + 4)
                player_weapons.add(new_flash)
                all_sprites.add(new_flash)

                self.bulletPause = 0

        else:
            self.bulletPause = 6

        # FIRE / CHARGE CANNON
        

        # DRONE CONTROL


        # SPEED DOWN
        if pressed_keys[K_q] or pressed_keys[K_KP7]:
            if self.speed > 3:
                if playerThrust.changingSpeed != True:

                    self.speed -= 2
                    playerThrust.changingSpeed = True
                    playerThrust.state = "retro"
                    playerThrust.counter = 0

        # SPEED UP
        if pressed_keys[K_LEFTBRACKET] or pressed_keys[K_KP_9]:
            if self.speed < 9:
                if playerThrust.changingSpeed != True:

                    self.speed += 2
                    playerThrust.changingSpeed = True
                    playerThrust.state = "boost"
                    playerThrust.counter = 0

        """ DEV CONTROLS (REMOVE ON RELEASE) """ 
        # GENERATE DRONE
        if pressed_keys[K_0]: # <~~~~~ This is how I've been adding the drone for testing

            if player.droneCount < 1:
                new_drone = Drone()
                drones.add(new_drone)
                all_sprites.add(new_drone)
                player.droneCount += 1

        # FORCE UPDATE DRONE
        if pressed_keys[K_9]:
            drones.update()   # <~~~~~ Another update attempt - forcing update with the 9 key

        """ PLAYER CONSTRAINTS """
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

        if self.rect.right > SCREEN_W:
            self.rect.right = SCREEN_W

        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.rect.top = 0

        if self.rect.bottom >= SCREEN_H:
            self.rect.bottom = SCREEN_H

""" PLAYER INSTANTIATION """
player = Player()
```

**Drone Class**

```
""" DRONE """
class Drone(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Drone, self).__init__()

        self.div = 52
        self.x = 0

        self.sheet = SpriteSheet( os.path.join( "gfx", "ares", "drone", "DroneSheet.png"))
        self.sheetArray = []
        self.sheet_W = self.sheet.sheet.get_rect().width
        while self.x < self.sheet_W:

            self.sheetArray.append( self.sheet.image_at( pg.Rect( self.x, 0, self.div, self.div)))
            self.x += self.div

        self.image = self.sheetArray[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.frameRate = 3
        self.counter = 0

        self.built = False

        self.lastPosition = []

        self.droneNumber = player.droneCount
        self.droneList = drones.sprites()

        if self.droneNumber == 0:

            for x in range(0, 10):
                self.lastPosition.append([player.rect.centerx, player.rect.centery])

            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(self.lastPosition[0][0], self.lastPosition[0][1]))

        elif self.droneNumber == 1:
            for x in range(0, 10):
                self.lastPosition.append([self.droneList[0].rect.centerx, self.droneList[0].rect.centery])

        elif self.droneNumber == 2:
            for x in range(0, 10):
                self.lastPosition.append([self.droneList[1].rect.centerx, self.droneList[1].rect.centery])

        elif self.droneNumber == 3:
            for x in range(0, 10):
                self.lastPosition.append([self.droneList[2].rect.centerx, self.droneList[2].rect.centery])

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(self.lastPosition[0][0], self.lastPosition[0][1]))

        def update(self):

            print("drone update") # <~~~~~ Test instruction that is not being called on drones.update()
            
            rate = self.frameRate
            arr = self.sheetArray

            if self.built == False:

                if self.counter == rate * 0:
                    self.image = arr[0]
                    sound.playSound(sound.pBoost, 0.3, 1)

                if self.counter == rate * 1: self.image = arr[1]
                if self.counter == rate * 2: self.image = arr[2]
                if self.counter == rate * 3: self.image = arr[3]
                if self.counter == rate * 4: self.image = arr[4]
                if self.counter == rate * 5: self.image = arr[5]
                if self.counter == rate * 6: self.image = arr[6]

                if self.counter == rate * 7:
                    self.built = True

                self.counter+=1

            self.droneList = drones.sprites()
            self.lastPosition.pop(0)

            if self.droneNumber == 0:
                self.lastPosition.append([player.rect.centerx, player.rect.centery])

            elif self.droneNumber == 1:
                self.lastPosition.append([self.droneList[0].rect.centerx, self.droneList[0].rect.centery])

            elif self.droneNumber == 2:
                self.lastPosition.append([self.droneList[1].rect.centerx, self.droneList[1].rect.centery])

            elif self.droneNumber == 3:
                self.lastPosition.append([self.droneList[2].rect.centerx, self.droneList[2].rect.centery])
        
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(self.lastPosition[0][0], self.lastPosition[0][1]))
```

**Update Manager Class**

```
""" UPDATE MANAGER """
class UpdateManager():

    def __init__(self):
        super(UpdateManager, self).__init__()

        self.ticks = 0
        self.seconds = 0

    def update(self, pressed_keys):

        self.ticks += 1
        if self.ticks % 60 == 0:
            self.seconds += 1
            print(self.seconds)

        # TITLE SCREEN
        if game.STATE == "title":

            if pressed_keys [K_ESCAPE]:
                game.STATE.RUNNING = False

            ui.update(pressed_keys)

        # MAIN GAME
        elif game.STATE == "active":

            if player.alive == False:
                all_sprites.add(playerThrust)
                all_sprites.add(player)
                player.alive = True

            for drone in drones:
                drone.update()
                print(drone)

            bg.update()
            player.update(pressed_keys)
            playerThrust.update()
            enemies.update()
            pickups.update()
            player_weapons.update()
            enemy_weapons.update()
            drones.update() # <~~~~~ Another attempt at processing updates...
                            #        If everything else updates here just fine, why won't the drones?? DX

        # PAUSE MENU
        elif game.STATE == "paused":

            if pressed_keys[K_q]:
                game.STATE.RUNNING = False

        # FINAL OUTPUT
        for item in all_sprites:
            SCREEN.blit(item.image, item.rect)

            if game.STATE == "paused":
                SCREEN.blit(disp.pauseImage, (300, 275))

""" UPDATER INSTANTIATION """
updater = UpdateManager()
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated - thank you!!

**EDIT** - Posting my main program would probably help ^ ^;

```
from display import *
from player import *
from enemies import *
from pickups import *
from logic import *
from sound import *

import pygame as pg
from pygame.locals import *

# SCREEN = disp.SCREENl
#SCREEN_W = disp.SCREEN_W
#SCREEN_H = disp.SCREEN_H

""" INSTANTIATION """
pg.init()

ADDENEMY = pg.USEREVENT + 1
pg.time.set_timer(ADDENEMY, 250)

""" MAIN """
clock = pg.time.Clock()

while game.RUNNING == True:
    SCREEN.fill((0,0,0))

    pressed_keys = pg.key.get_pressed()

    for event in pg.event.get():

        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:

                if game.STATE == "active":
                    game.STATE = "paused"
                    pg.mixer.music.pause()
                    sound.playSound(sound.pause, 0.3, 0)

                elif game.STATE == "paused":
                    game.STATE = "active"
                    pg.mixer.music.unpause()

            #elif event.key == K_m:

                #if 

        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            game.STATE.RUNNING = False

    updater.update(pressed_keys)

    if pg.sprite.spritecollideany(player, enemies):
        player.kill()

    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pg.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a matter on [indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation). The indentation of `def update(self):` is wrong and so `update` is not a method of `Drone`, but a function in `Drone.__init__`. Change the indentation

```py
class Drone(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Drone, self).__init__()
        # [...]

    #<--| indentation
    def update(self, pressed_keys):
        # [...]
```

Comment: * Facepalm of great power * Thank you so very much, kind sir, you are my hero.